# Feature extraction from multiple images in python using SIFT

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

In feature extraction and detection using SIFT, I could extract features from 2 image. But I have 400 frames in video and want to have features from all 400 images in python. Can someone help me out with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key-points extracted from SIFT describe numerous features. If you wish to compare all 400 frames from a video to an image that you have, you will have to make a loop over your process and run SIFT iteratively. This will be computationally expensive.

One method to make this fast would be to read all key-points of these 400 frames and store them into a file so that you don't have to detect them each time you want to compare them with a test image.

This is what I've made from the question that you've asked.